# New Installation working but no page formatting

Tags: magento2.3.5-p1

[image]I have installed version 2.3.5 p1 on my windows server 2016 PC and have the site running so you can log in at admin and also view the site.

In all cases the pages are shown with no template or images.

I know I am also braking the rules as the site is on IIS which i have to use due to exchange sever web requirements.

I hope its a simple fix.
[image]

Comment: Most likely culprits are either improper file permissions or you installed with a php user that doesn't have proper permissions. I don't know enough about IIS to guide you further but based on what you described it is the most likely culprit. If you open developer tools you will see 404's for the CSS and JS files.

Comment: I have set permissions as read/write for all at this time.

Answer (score 0):

Please Go to Magento Root Directory in `shell` or `terminal` and run this command

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Answer (score 0):

Thnankyou for the advice. I have ran this command previously and tried again. It seams to run OK but does not resolve the problem.

As below.
[image]

Comment: try to tun command with your store language like `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f  EN_Us`

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, the css files are not loaded and if you right click the homepage and go to "View page source" you will find out that by clicking the css file link, it gives 500 internal error. Try remove the .htaccess file from pub/ and then run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`.

Comment: I have tried this but with no change, I have added another picture showing the source view on home page, I can see that the link with /version158... is a none existent folder

Answer (score 0):

got a little closer. it seems to be a web.config issue with the css. I have added this code from web. in web.config file.

Issue now resolved

---

```
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <clear />
                <!-- HTTP_AUTHORIZATION variable removed-->
                <rule name="TRACE and TRACK HTTP methods 2" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions>
                        <!-- TRACE and TRACK HTTP methods disabled to prevent XSS attacks-->
                        <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^TRAC[EK]" ignoreCase="false" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Temporary" url="{R:0}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Route requests to index.php 2" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/(media|skin|js)/" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="pub/index.php" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
<!--Custom configuration for the pub/static directory-->
<location path="pub/static">
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <clear/>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 1-1 - pub" stopProcessing="false">
                    <match url="^pub/static/version.+?/(.+)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="pub/static/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="false">
                    <match url="^pub/static/(.+)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="pub/static.php?resource={R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```